# Need to get GUI app to shut off to many processes in 20.04.02

Tags: battery, fan

Noob question... sorry!
New question on old problem! Only a year old user and can't locate any apps installed except with hTop, and it's may be great, but way to overwhelming!

The reason I wanted a good GUI for shutting down processes that SHOW running process in graph, is I installed, and was setting up 20,04, yesterday and ... my laptop "fan" is on "ALL the time."
And I have 100% battery, and if I unplug I see after 20 seconds, 1hr and 16 min left.

But if I'm running Win10, and all things shut off I can shut off, Fan runs for startup for 2 to 4 minutes and stops!
And I just unplugged and see 6 hr. 20 minutes left on battery!
The 5 hour difference is totally appalling!

I had super battery in 18.04 to 18.06 but tried to install and didn't have, or could not connect to internet. So that was tossed to the curb! I was going to install 18.06, and reinstall my Deja Dup backup, and than upgrade to 20.04 but curbed that also! That would have been SUPER, but!

Tried Synaptic installed hTop, and need a "professional interpreter"
to decipher the thing!

So I need a simple GUI program graph that I can TURN off the things I don't need or use, (and see it in applications)...that is causing the fan and CPU to Max out! I have an Asus Ryzen f412da for what ever that's worth!

Comment: Thank you very much, and I will be trying out those suggestions, you all shared, and I didn't find do "Searches" before I asked! Be doing them asap, within, 3 days of real bad weather here, so I'll be shut in to do so...! THANKS again!

Comment: PS.... I "Tried" System Monitor" but ticked icon in "Applications" and it didn't start up at all !       
 And tried Terminal sudo apt run system-monitor but that was wrong input code because it didn't run? Made sure it was installed via Synaptic, and it was! Back in a few days about the other suggestions! THANKS!

Comment: htop will make perfect sense to you after you've used Linux long enough. Play around with changing the layout, as that will help make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There are two system monitoring tools supported by gnome.

A simple one: `sudo apt install gnome-usage` ([source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-usage))

A more featured one: `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` ([source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor))

Hope this helps !

Comment: Though very nice, gnome-usage and -system-monitor only shows which processes that are running, not what  services they belong to. You wouldn't want to shut down a single process belonging to a database or web-server, but instead shut down the service.